# How to skip a line of code inside a class during compiling

Tags: iphone, ios, debugging, compilation

I have allocated and initialized a class file which is not in the project workspace (don't have a file to import).Normally it would throw an error like Use of undeclared identifier classname.Here i want to skip this error make the build success.Is there any pragma to skip these kind of error's.

Comment: #ifdef SOMEVALUE /* some code */ #endif , is it what you want?

Comment: yes.. worked like charm..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the code around `#ifdef` and `#endif` macros and do not define the macro name that is used.

Example

```
- (void)myMethod 
{
  // .... 

 #ifdef MYMACRO
     // Here you need not #import ABC.h
     ABC *abc = [[ABC alloc] init];
     [abc someMethod]
 #endif
  // .....
}
```

Do not `#define MYMACRO` anywhere so that this code block is ignored by the compiler.

Hope that helps!